# Agregar y eliminar datos de un JComboBox

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

estoy creando un programa con conexión a BD y estoy agregando productos con un JComboBox pero quiero ver cómo puedo agregar un producto de un JtextField al JComboBox y como eliminar solo un registro del mismo JComboBox con un botón, hasta ahorita llevo esto de código

```
String datosprod = txtProd.getText();
String datosmat = txtMaterial.getText();
String datoscol = txtColor.getText();

if (cbProducto.getSelectedItem().equals("Seleccionar") || cbMaterial.getSelectedItem().equals("Seleccionar") || cbMaterial.getSelectedItem().equals("Bolsa")
        || cbMaterial.getSelectedItem().equals("Sombrero") || cbMaterial.getSelectedItem().equals("Toquilla")
        || cbColor.getSelectedItem().equals("Seleccionar")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debes ingresar el Producto, Material o Color");
} else {
    cbProducto.addItem(datosprod);
    txtProd.setText("");
    cbMaterial.addItem(datosmat);
    txtMaterial.setText("");
    cbColor.addItem(datoscol);
    txtColor.setText("");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha actualizado la lista");
}
```

Comment: Hola YMG, bienvenido, no me queda claro tu problema, **cbProducto.addItem( datosprod );** y similares, son la forma correcta de agregar items, para quitar usas **cbProducto.removeItem( datosprod );**, entonces si tu código no está funcionandom para agregar, debe ser por la condición del "if", no puedo decir más sin los datos que no aportas (por ejem. el array con que cargas el "combo".